# mailto params not recognized

Tags: html, mailto

All - I running an application outside android that is publishing emails for users.  Some of these users are mobile users and of those mobile users, some of them are on android.  When viewing the HTML based emails in the native client, the users can click on an HREF mailto that should open a new mail window with pre-populated subject and body.  For some reason, this works with K-9 and all other mobile platforms, but in the native client it is not.  Here is my mailto:

```
<a href="mail to:%Bind(:1)?cc=%Bind(:2)&bcc=%Bind(:3)&subject=%Bind(:4)&body=%Bind(:5)">%Bind(:6)</a>
```

Dont worry, the binds do get populated :).  In the native client the mailto opens the window the the "TO" field correct, however, for CC and BCC I get a "," the subject and body are empty.

Any ideas?

Comment: I would be curious to see what the completed anchor tag and its href attribute look like once the binds are populated.  I suspect that you have a double quote character embedded in the cc: field or subsequent fields.  In the SO text box, type the hyperlink on its own line with four spaces in front and SO will render it as code.

Comment: Thanks Dave.  Ill run a test tonight and post my results.